# How do I properly use MagicalRecord for importing data from a webservice without blocking the UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using Magical Record in my application to parse server responses to generate / update / delete my datamodel objects and also use it to make alle the fetches i need in my app.

For the importing I have my own abstraction class that has two methods.
Also I could replace MagicalRecord for the importing very easy that way.

```
- (void)importInBackgroundUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
```

and

```
- (void)saveInBackgroundUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(void (^)(BOOL success))completion
```

The importInBackground is used for all the data that i get via the API. In my case those calls are all made after a AFNetworking request.
The saveInBackground is used whenever the user interacts with the app so that something need to change in the DB. This second method is so that I can prioritize stuff that the user caused (as he wants immediate feedback).

In my abstraction class i also have two serial queues (one for each method) so that I have two different background threads.

Those methods now look like that...

```
- (void)saveInBackgroundUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(void (^)())completion
{
    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, ^{
        [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:block];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion)
            {
                completion();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem now is that if i have a look at the app in Instruments, I see that a lot of the time (for the save) is spent on the main thread.
Also the saveInBackground often has to wait for import to finish, which I don't really understand...

It seems as if

```
- (void)MR_saveWithOptions:(MRSaveContextOptions)mask completion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)completion;
```

called on the main thread for saving the parent of the context. This seems to be the main context. But why can it be that saving the original context where changes happend is fast, but saving the main context is taking so long?!? I understand that changes have to be merged... but it's taking much much longer than the original save?!?

Can I have a separate context for saving to disc? Would that help in my case?

Would be great if you guys could help me improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. The way you are using `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:` is dangerous at least.

   Method `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:` seems to be designed for a "thread confinement" approach, where a managed object context is associated to a *particular* thread.

   However, you are invoking the method from within a block which is dispatched to a dispatch queue. There is no direct relation between a queue and a thread, that is there is no such particular thread. Thus, `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:` won't work here for you. You can expect crashes.
2. The reason why you see a lot of work executed on the main thread, is that (probably) the *default* managed object context, where the persistent store coordinator has been assigned, is associated to the main thread. In other words, all the *heavy* work - namely saving and fetching the model objects to and from the persistent store is executed on the *main* thread.

   It sounds weird, that it is explicitly recommended (in the docs) to have the default context associated to the *main* thread - even it's doing the heavy work. It makes probably more sense to have a managed object context which is using a private queue which is the ultimate "root" context where the persistent sore is assigned to. Any child context may then be either associated to the main thread or any other private dispatch queue.

   It may be reasonable to have the default context execute on the main thread, but it should have a parent context, and the ultimate root context shall handle the persistent store and should execute on a private queue.

Edit:

After digging into the sources of MagicalRecord, I have to say, that method `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait:` is actually wonky: it creates a context with a private queue, which is not suitable for thread confinement. Expect something bad happening.

Comment: Thanks for you answer...
So if I am not using my own queues, how can I realize that I have two contexts? One for UI changes (with high priority) and one for API imports?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with MR, except for the issue I mentioned. MR tries to be smart, but unfortunately, there seems to be an error in the implementation. But as a general rule of thumb: Think of a managed object living *in* a certain managed object context, and this context is associated to a certain execution context (either thread or queue). Accessing a managed object is only valid when executing in this same execution context (either thread or queue). You can ensure that, by using `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` where the object's moc is the receiver.

Comment: e.g. `[obj.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{ NSLog(@"Name: %@", obj.name);}];`. Sending messages to the context must also be executed in the same context: `[moc performBlock:^{ NSError* error; [moc save:&error;]}];`

Comment: Note that MR already creates "local" and "temporary" contexts.

Comment: Well I know that... but the ``saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait``method is actually using ``performBlockAndWait``. So what should be the big threat here?
Also I of course only access my managed objects in the block that i pass in and nowhere else.

Comment: Then, you are safe. Well, `saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlockAndWait` will use performBlockAndWait: to execute your block. However, don't assume this has something to do with the *current thread*. Actually, the *current thread* is totally unrelated to the execution context where your block will be executed. Don't access these managed objects in the *current thread*. At least this method is a misnomer, and probably a relict of earlier versions where CoreData had only thread confinement. It's just an unnecessary elaborated wrapper for a temporary context where you execute your block.

Comment: Note though, that "safe" doesn't mean you should get better performance. As already explained in my answer, the persistent store should be assigned to a context which is associated to a private queue. This should be the "root" context. A "main" context (associated to the main thread or main queue) should be a child of the "root" context. Maybe you can configure MR to adopt this Core Data Stack?